# Forcing Date Cells to Retain 10-character Date ("mm/dd/yyyy")

Tags: vba, excel

I'm scraping some data off of a website where one column contains a day and date, formatted like `Thu 09/06/2018`. I just want to keep the `09/06/2018` part, but it seems like no matter what I do, Excel converts the date to `9/6/2018`. **I need the full `09/06/2018` (not just formatted, visible in the formula bar)** in order for the data to be accepted into a database - how can I force excel to retain this data as text?

Below is my code, at the bottom is my attempt to `'Fix Dates`

```
'Fix Dates
Application.CutCopyMode = False
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Cells
        cell.NumberFormat = "@"
        cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = Right(cell.Value, 10)
    Next cell

    For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Cells
        cell.NumberFormat = "@"
        cell.Offset(0, -9).Value = cell.Value
    Next cell

Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.Delete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are copying to column k then back to column B, jsut do it all in B in 1 step.

```
'Run this loop on the cell itself rather than column K.
For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Cells
    cell.NumberFormat = "@"
    cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, 10) 'Removed offset
Next cell

'Remove this loop and the subsequent delete
'For Each cell In Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Cells
'    cell.NumberFormat = "@"
'    cell.Offset(0, -9).Value = cell.Value
'Next cell

'Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks, Valon. I've tried that, but that only formats the data cosmetically. In the formula bar, you can see that the data will still be in the `m/d/yyyy` format, which won't work unfortunately.

Comment: I have updated my solution. I also realized that your second loop is redundant. you can skip it completely.